# How to match/pair two array elements with each other and return only one in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Is it possible to match all `email_adr` and `ad_owner_email` and keep one? For example `[0]` and `[1]` is a match and `[0]` or `[1]` gets deleted in the filtered array. It's ok to get "cross matched" through all `["email_adr"]` and `["ad_owner_email"]` elements.

```
 array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "14598"
        ["email_adr"]=>
        string(14) "jos@pl.nuu"
        ["ad_owner_email"]=>
        string(23) "boo@gmail.qom"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "14598"
        ["email_adr"]=>
        string(23) "boo@gmail.qom"
        ["ad_owner_email"]=>
        string(14) "jos@pl.nuu"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(5) "14598"
        ["email_adr"]=>
        string(23) "boo@gmail.qom"
        ["ad_owner_email"]=>
        string(21) "pelle@med.nuu"
      }
    }
```

### Desired result:

```
 array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(3) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(5) "14598"
            ["email_adr"]=>
            string(23) "boo@gmail.qom"
            ["ad_owner_email"]=>
            string(14) "jos@pl.nuu"
          }
          [1]=>
          array(3) {
            ["id"]=>
            string(5) "14598"
            ["email_adr"]=>
            string(23) "boo@gmail.qom"
            ["ad_owner_email"]=>
            string(21) "pelle@med.nuu"
          }
        }
```

Comment: Show desired output. How it should looks like.

Comment: Hope its clearer now

Comment: Yeah, now it's understandable, will try to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first step you can collect all possible email pairs into `$tmp` array:

```
foreach($array as $record){
    $tmp1[$record['email_adr']][] = $record['ad_owner_email']; 
}
```

This will create array like:

```
Array
(
    [jos@pl.nuu] => Array
        (
            [0] => boo@gmail.qom
        )

    [boo@gmail.qom] => Array
        (
            [0] => pelle@med.nuu
            [1] => jos@pl.nuu
        ) 
)
```

Now you can use further logic:

```
foreach($array as $ind=>$record){
    if (isset($tmp1[$record['ad_owner_email']]) && !empty($tmp1[$record['ad_owner_email']]) )
    { 
        if (in_array($record['email_adr'],$tmp1[$record['ad_owner_email']])) 
        { 
            // index of current value in $tmp1 array
            $tm1 = array_search($record['ad_owner_email'],$tmp1[$record['email_adr']]); 

            // delete an element from $tmp1 and from $array
            unset($tmp1[$record['email_adr']][$tm1]); 
            unset($array[$ind]);  
        }
    }     
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/uH7kU)**

**EDIT**
According to the request below

```html
$array = [["id"=>"111","email_adr"=>"AAA","ad_owner_email"=>"BBB"],  
          ["id"=>"111","email_adr"=>"BBB","ad_owner_email"=>"CCC"],
          ["id"=>"111","email_adr"=>"BBB","ad_owner_email"=>"AAA"], <--discarded
          ["id"=>"500","email_adr"=>"QQQ","ad_owner_email"=>"PPP"],  
          ["id"=>"500","email_adr"=>"PPP","ad_owner_email"=>"QQQ"], <--discarded
          ["id"=>"1000","email_adr"=>"PPP","ad_owner_email"=>"QQQ"], <-saved because id=1000 and differs from id=500 
    ];

--------==::Desired result::==-----------
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 111
            [email_adr] => AAA
            [ad_owner_email] => BBB
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 111
            [email_adr] => BBB
            [ad_owner_email] => CCC
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 500
            [email_adr] => QQQ
            [ad_owner_email] => PPP
        )
    
     [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1000
            [email_adr] => PPP
            [ad_owner_email] => QQQ
        )
)
```

you can use next logic instead of previous:

```
// removes duplicate elements from multidimentional array
$array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);

// foreach($array ...) //<-- creating an array $tmp1

foreach($array as $ind=>$record){

    $id       = $record['id'];
    $em_owner = $record['ad_owner_email'];
    $em_adr   = $record['email_adr'];

    if (isset( $tmp1[$id][$em_owner] ) && 
        !empty( $tmp1[$id][$em_owner] ) && 
        in_array( $em_adr,   $tmp1[$id][$em_owner] ) &&
        in_array( $em_owner, $tmp1[$id][$em_adr] )
        )
    {    
        // indexes of pair values (both, direct and vice versa)
        $tm1 = array_search($em_adr,   $tmp1[$id][$em_owner]);
        $tm2 = array_search($em_owner, $tmp1[$id][$em_adr]);

        // index of the row in main data set where these values a placed in defined positions.
        $in = getIndex($array, ['a'=>$em_owner, 'b'=>$em_adr, 'c'=>$id]);

            // removing data about paired values in $tmp1 array and in the main $array 
            unset( $tmp1[$id][$em_adr][$tm2] );  
            unset( $tmp1[$id][$em_owner][$tm1] );  
            unset( $array[$in] );  
    }     
} 

// additional function for receiving index of the row
function getIndex($data,$ne){
    foreach($data as $key=>$val){
        if ($val['id'] === $ne['c'] && $val['email_adr'] === $ne['a'] && $val['ad_owner_email'] === $ne['b']) return $key;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**[Demo2](https://3v4l.org/e5Bd7)**

If you have a problem with `SORT_REGULAR` then you can use [next code](https://3v4l.org/iijMT) instead of mentioned `array_unique()`:

```
$array = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
```

Comment: Hi! Many many thanks it works perfectly! Would it be hard to keep (not deleting) ["id"]:s that differs? For example if [0]["id"]=500 then keep it? (even if the emails matches)

Comment: I mean like this https://3v4l.org/6FANA  i own you a beer by now.

Comment: @Jonas, you can use [this](https://3v4l.org/rcZBt) code. It discards yours defined rows

Comment: I can't quite get it to work see https://3v4l.org/to3qR I'm really impressed that you are helping me!

Comment: @Jonas, yeah, updated, added searching of unset index `$in` with 3 arguments instead of 2

Comment: Some duplicates are still there :) See https://3v4l.org/VsaNN  I admire your work!

Comment: @Jonas, hah, it's simple, just use [array_unique()](https://3v4l.org/e5Bd7)

Comment: Hi again it works excellent!! Give me an BTC receiving address and ill send you a beer. ONE last question. See https://3v4l.org/j1svj

Comment: @Jonas, Hi hi, I don't have it, or I've created it a years ago and I'm not using it cause don't know how to) I see, you can [use this code](https://3v4l.org/7DZ0Z) The new column is sorted in ASC order, hence a value of this date will be the oldest one

Comment: @Jonas, you're welcome)) btw you can finally accept answer)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you on your way. Taking the original array, `$arr` we loop through all elements and compare `email_adr` to `ad_owner_email`, as follows:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($arr[$key+1])) {
        if ($value['email_adr'] == $arr[$key + 1]['ad_owner_email']) {
            unset($arr[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/hEud7)

Comment: What if [1] will be at [2] index and vice versa? https://3v4l.org/CoKPW